# How to override RoleAdapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

I am trying to override RoleAdapter in initializer file ***config/initializers/rolify.rb***:

```
Rolify::Role.class_eval do
  def has_role?(role_name, resource = nil)
    # The code works here
  end
end

require 'rolify/adapters/active_record/role_adapter'

Rolify::Adapter::RoleAdapter.class_eval do
  def build_query(role, resource = nil)
    # The code are not picked up
  end
end
```

But that does not work as usual, my changes are not picked up, weird. Any idea about this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making this change?

Comment: @emaillenin Of course i did it :P